# Nodejs multiple async requests instantly fail

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I've been writing a bot for Discord which I've found to be failing due to multiple async responses being empty. It seems to only do 8 requests and ignores the others.

Running excerpt from code:

```
/*Required modules
  npm install request //used because it supports HTTPS
  npm install cheerio
*/
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var ids = [
        "16286",
        "16296",
        "16284",
        "15563",
        "15964",
        "15123",
        "15592",
        "868",
        "15626",
        "15627",
        "339",
        "350"
    ];

var print = "";
var count = 0;
for(var x=0;x<ids.length;x++) {
    request({uri: "https://www.futbin.com" + "/17/player/"+ids[x], gzip: true}, function(error, response, full) {
        let $ = cheerio.load(full);
        var bins = $('.lowest_bin_next_tr');
        var header = $('.player_header').text().trim().split("-");
        console.log(header);
        if(header != '') {
        print += header[1].trim() + ", " + header[0] + "OVR " + $('.pcdisplay-pos').text().trim() + "\r\n";
        print += "**PS4:** " + $('#pslbin').text().slice(0, -1) + ", " + bins.eq(0).text().split("d")[1].trim() + ", " + bins.eq(1).text().split("d")[1].trim() + " " + $('.lowest_bin_updated_tr_ps4').text().trim().substring(8, this.length) + "\r\n";
        print += "**XBOX:** " + $('#xboxlbin').text().slice(0, -1) + ", " + bins.eq(4).text().split("d")[1].trim() + ", " + bins.eq(5).text().split("d")[1].trim() + " " + $('.lowest_bin_updated_tr_xb1').text().trim().substring(8, this.length) + "\r\n"; "\r\n";
        }
        if(++count == ids.length)
            callback(print);
    });
}
```

4 requests instantly fail since there are 12 ids. Why does this only fulfill 8 requests?

Comment: try console.log the error and check why the requests are failing

Comment: The host server could see your rapid fire 12 requests as a denial of service or rate limiting violation.  You need to look at the exact errors and maybe the network trace to see exactly what the failures are.  You may also want to know that your requests can arrive back in any order so the order you will get them in the `print` variable can be random (it depends upon the specific behavior of the host server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when I run your code, the first four responses to return create an empty `header` variable.  The result of:

```
$('.player_header').text().trim().split("-");
```

is an empty string.

But, every time I run it, I get a different four that are empty.  I think this is some sort of server-side problem when you send it 12 rapid fire requests.

In a test, if I slow the requests down to one request per second, all 12 report data.  This is definitely some server-side issue where it does not like getting that many requests at once.

Here's an example of test code that slows the requests down to one per second that works just fine.  I'm not suggesting this is production code, but wanted to show you the code that makes a request once per second that succeeds:

```
/*Required modules
  npm install request //used because it supports HTTPS
  npm install cheerio
*/
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var ids = [
        "16286",
        "16296",
        "16284",
        "15563",
        "15964",
        "15123",
        "15592",
        "868",
        "15626",
        "15627",
        "339",
        "350"
    ];

var print = "";
var count = 0;
ids.forEach(function(id, x) {   
    setTimeout(() => {
        request({uri: "https://www.futbin.com" + "/17/player/"+id, gzip: true}, function(error, response, full) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                let $ = cheerio.load(full);
                var bins = $('.lowest_bin_next_tr');
                console.log(`header data [${id}]`, `"${$('.player_header').text().trim()}"`);
                var header = $('.player_header').text().trim().split("-");
                if(header != '') {
                    print += header[1].trim() + ", " + header[0] + "OVR " + $('.pcdisplay-pos').text().trim() + "\r\n";
                    print += "**PS4:** " + $('#pslbin').text().slice(0, -1) + ", " + bins.eq(0).text().split("d")[1].trim() + ", " + bins.eq(1).text().split("d")[1].trim() + " " + $('.lowest_bin_updated_tr_ps4').text().trim().substring(8, this.length) + "\r\n";
                    print += "**XBOX:** " + $('#xboxlbin').text().slice(0, -1) + ", " + bins.eq(4).text().split("d")[1].trim() + ", " + bins.eq(5).text().split("d")[1].trim() + " " + $('.lowest_bin_updated_tr_xb1').text().trim().substring(8, this.length) + "\r\n"; "\r\n";
                }
                if(++count == ids.length)
                    callback(print);
            }
        });
    }, x * 1000);
});

function callback(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

FYI, it also works if I strictly serialize them (one request in flight at at time) like this:

```
/*Required modules
  npm install request //used because it supports HTTPS
  npm install cheerio
*/
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = Promise.promisify(require('request'), {multiArgs: true});
var cheerio = require('cheerio');



var ids = [
        "16286",
        "16296",
        "16284",
        "15563",
        "15964",
        "15123",
        "15592",
        "868",
        "15626",
        "15627",
        "339",
        "350"
    ];

Promise.mapSeries(ids, function(id) {
    return request({uri: "https://www.futbin.com" + "/17/player/"+id, gzip: true}).then(function(data) {
        var response = data[0];
        var full = data[1];
        let $ = cheerio.load(full);
        var bins = $('.lowest_bin_next_tr');
        console.log(`header data [${id}]`, `"${$('.player_header').text().trim()}"`);
        var header = $('.player_header').text().trim().split("-");
        let print = "";
        if(header != '') {
            print += header[1].trim() + ", " + header[0] + "OVR " + $('.pcdisplay-pos').text().trim() + "\r\n";
            print += "**PS4:** " + $('#pslbin').text().slice(0, -1) + ", " + bins.eq(0).text().split("d")[1].trim() + ", " + bins.eq(1).text().split("d")[1].trim() + " " + $('.lowest_bin_updated_tr_ps4').text().trim().substring(8, this.length) + "\r\n";
            print += "**XBOX:** " + $('#xboxlbin').text().slice(0, -1) + ", " + bins.eq(4).text().split("d")[1].trim() + ", " + bins.eq(5).text().split("d")[1].trim() + " " + $('.lowest_bin_updated_tr_xb1').text().trim().substring(8, this.length) + "\r\n"; "\r\n";
        }
        return print;
    });
}).then(function(results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: @inuyasha555 - FYI, it also works if I strictly serialize the requests to only one in flight at a time (second block of code in my answer).  This second scheme also preserves the order of the responses to line up with the order of the requests.

Answer (score 1):

```
'strict mode';
var async = require('async'),
request = require('request');

var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var ids = [
    "16286",
    "16296",
    "16284",
    "15563",
    "15964",
    "15123",
    "15592",
    "868",
    "15626",
    "15627",
    "339",
    "350"
];

var print = "";

async.eachSeries(ids , idsIteration , finishIteration);

function idsIteration(id , callBack){
    processId(id , callBack);
}


function processId(id , cb){
    request({uri: "https://www.futbin.com" + "/17/player/"+id, gzip: true}, function(error, response, full) {
    if(error){
        console.log('there was error entertainting request :' + error);
        cb(error);
    }
    else {
        var c = cheerio.load(full);
        var bins = c('.lowest_bin_next_tr');
        var header = c('.player_header').text().trim().split("-");
        console.log(header);
        if(header != '') {
        print += header[1].trim() + ", " + header[0] + "OVR " + c('.pcdisplay-pos').text().trim() + "\r\n";
        print += "**PS4:** " + c('#pslbin').text().slice(0, -1) + ", " + bins.eq(0).text().split("d")[1].trim() + ", " + bins.eq(1).text().split("d")[1].trim() + " " + c('.lowest_bin_updated_tr_ps4').text().trim().substring(8, this.length) + "\r\n";
        print += "**XBOX:** " + c('#xboxlbin').text().slice(0, -1) + ", " + bins.eq(4).text().split("d")[1].trim() + ", " + bins.eq(5).text().split("d")[1].trim() + " " + c('.lowest_bin_updated_tr_xb1').text().trim().substring(8, this.length) + "\r\n"; "\r\n";
        }
        cb();
        }
    });
}
function finishIteration(){
    console.log('all ids processed');
}
```

OutPut on my console: [image]

Comment: And why exactly will this fix the problem?

Comment: this wont flush the requests and its some what like you did in your answer but in a different way. @jfriend00

Comment: You confused me with the term "flush".  Perhaps what you're trying to say is that this will serialize the requests to have only one at a time in flight?  Did you try it to see if it works?

Comment: Yes flush means that. and this async.eachSeries will send one request at a time and wont entertain another request until callback is called. ANd yes i did ran this on my pc. Updated my answer for you @jfriend00

Comment: To improve your answer, you should explain all that in your answer so people know why you think your answer solves the OP's problem.  Just posting code and telling people to try something (even if it's the right code) is never as good an answer as also explaining what you changed and why it solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your advice :)